# Activation Function to help find anomalies

Tags: python, anomaly-detection, activation-function, sigmoid

So I have one column of data, all the data there is normal and without any anomalies.
Let’s say the data is scattered just like the picture bellow.

[image]

K-means doesn’t really work on one column. I was given the advice to plot the data and then use an activation function preferably sigmoid (but there might be others that would work aswell) to include most of the data within.

After that add the anomalies which would be further away from the activation function and then basically say if a value is this far away from the activation function (plays the role of a threshold)   call that value as an anomaly

[image]

I am looking for some advice regarding this, I think the idea behind it it is not bad.

Comment: This is basically a 2-class classification problem. There are any number of methods to look into. For instance, support vector classifiers, come to mind.

Comment: @wraped, Does svm follow the same concept ? and Could you please tell what other 2-class classification methods would you use ?

Comment: I recommend using your favourite search engine to find `binary classification algorithm`

Comment: @wraped, however thr svm seems to be just linear and using suck activation function as sigmoid that wont be the case . Looking at how scatter my data is I am scared the SVM might classify wrongly

Comment: Look into kernelized svms then. Besides, your dataset can easily be separated with a linear classifier.

Comment: What are the axes of your plots? Seem like you have 2 feature columns, not 1?

Comment: Use one of the Anomaly Detection models in scikit-learn. No need to try to manually find any activation function etc. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_anomaly_comparison.html

Comment: @jonnor, more like the normal data in one column and then I use a for loop function to add anomalies to that column .

Comment: So the x axis is just your sample id's? And this is not a time series?

Comment: @jonnor , yes. No the data is not in time series, I get the data from my dataframe which is in a csv format

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to compute an anomaly score, and then to set a threshold on this score for what to consider an anomaly.

A simple method is to model the data as normally distributed (Gaussian), compute the mean and standard deviation of the distribution. Then for each new sample, compute anomaly score as the number of standard deviations away from the distribution mean. Then you threshold that, for example at 3 standard deviations (exact value must be decided on a True vs False Positive preference).

When generalized to a multivariate dataset this is known as the Mahalanobis distance, and is frequently applied to anomaly detection.
This is what the [EllipticEnvelope model in scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.covariance.EllipticEnvelope.html) uses.

Comment: If I understood it right. Get the mean and std of the data and then in my case when I add the anomalies, they will be bigger than max value of the data and so be outside the borders of the sigma and thus consider them as anomalies. Consideration: my dataset is it not normally distrubuted

Comment: Small deviations from normal distribution is rarely problematic. If it is very off, you can normalize your distribution. Using a power transform, or Box-Cox

Comment: my std for the dataset of the scatter plot from above is quite huge . std 999.622543

Comment: could you please have a look at [THIS](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/69434/many-separation-line-using-rbg-kernel-in-svm). I having been working to find the threshold an suck the anomalies using SVM approach

Comment: I tried to use SVM but it is really slow, I am looking for a way that I can make use of Mean and Standard Deviation but also the use of Sigmoid function  from Activation Function ( this to be used as a threshold) . Any advice regarding this ?

Comment: Using the sigmoid as a threshold on 1d data does not make any sense.

Comment: using the somgoid curve for the way to include most of the data inside and then adding anomalies that exceed these boundries, then as a final part, use these boundry to detect how far away the anomalies are from the threshold.